# How to set the display format of timestamp in Apache IoTDB to yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ?

Tags: time-series, timestamp, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I know that Apache IoTDB can support `LONG` type and `DATETIME-DISPLAY` type when displaying timestamps. Also, the `DATETIME-DISPLAY` type can support user-defined time format. May I ask where to set the display format of this timestamp? Also, anyone can tell me what parameter should I change to set the display method of timestamp in IoTDB? (I want the timestamp to be look like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set time_display_type=xxx` command in Cli tool of Apache IoTDB to change the display of timestamp (this command is specially adaptable for Cli tool of IoTDB). You can set the `xxx` part of `time_display_type` to, for example, `long`, `default`, `lS08601`, or `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` as you need.